# How to add data in grocery crud with session data

Tags: session, addition, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

I want to know about, adding data in grocery crud using session data.

Here My Session Data:

```
Array ( [username] => admin [privilage] => 1 )
```

and here's my function:

```
try{
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $data = $CI->session->userdata('logged_in');
            print_r($data); exit();
            $createdby = $data['username'];


            $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
            $crud->set_table('tablecontent');
            $crud->set_subject('News');
            $crud->set_field_upload('img','assets/uploads/files');
            $crud->set_relation('idCategory','tablecategory','namaCategory');
            $output = $crud->render();

            $this->_example_output($output);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
        }
```

why i want to do this is because i want user know who add the data.

cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite late but someone might find this useful.

You can add session information to a field using:

```
$crud->callback_add_field('user_id',array($this,'user_id_callback'));
```

Then right the following function within the controller:

```
function user_id_callback()
{
    return '<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" value="'.$this->session->userdata('user_details')[0]->name.'" name="user_id" style="width:462px">';
}
```

This might help: http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/callback_add_field_example